# SE data explorer shows Ask Ubuntu logo which has white font

Tags: bug, data-explorer, design, logo

In the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/queries), the Ask Ubuntu logo is shown as:

[image: Screenshot of Ask Ubuntu logo in SEDE]

This is the image being displayed: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/askubuntu/img/logo.png

when indeed it should have the "speech-bubble" portion visible. Looking at the image carefully shows that it should (if I am correct) be transparent around the white speech bubble, which isn't visible at all. Some users, as seen in comments below, believe that the icons from the [site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites) should be used, which I agree with.

<sub>I wasn't sure whether this belongs here because it is about the design of the Data Explorer, or on Ask Ubuntu Meta because of the logo design, so feel free to migrate if it is in the wrong place.</sub>

Comment: Ah, right, this was only fixed on the front page. I think it makes more sense to switch to the touch icons that are shown on the [Stack Exchange sites list](http://stackexchange.com/sites) all the places that the logo is shown now, which would help here.

Comment: You can edit it in as a suggested fix if you want. It's something that's kind of on the to-do list already anyway, this just reminded me.

Comment: @TimStine Edited in.