# Ask Ubuntu logo partially invisible on Data.SE

Tags: bug, design, data-explorer, logo

[image: ask_blank]

Yeah, this hasn't been patched since 2012 [[SE data explorer shows bad Ask Ubuntu logo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155152/se-data-explorer-shows-bad-ask-ubuntu-logo) ]

Comment: @Mat I've already linked it... The only reason I reposted it was because the issue hasn't been resolved in 4 years...

Comment: Still a dup. If you care about the issue, post a bounty. Or edit the post (meaningfully) to bump it.