# Obfuscated Ask Ubuntu logo when composing a query on SEDE

Tags: bug, design, data-explorer, logo

When [composing a query for Ask Ubuntu](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/new) on SEDE, the logo for that site in the upper-right corner shows up like this:

[image]

Without the "Ubuntu" part, and it looks like this happens elsewhere on SEDE as well.  I assume this is because the "Ubuntu" part of the actual logo is white on a white background, but on-site, it looks like this:

[image]

If we're going to keep just the "Ask", can we update it to have the red bubble around it like on the main SEDE page? Like this:

[image]

Comment: Now, I've just found https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155152.  Before y'all VTC as a duplicate, I'd like to point out that that was asked in 2012, has been viewed just eighty times and *still* hasn't been fixed despite other duplicates from back then.  I think this needs to be brought to attention again.

Comment: I understand your desire to bring attention to an old issue which hasn't gotten action, but there are supported ways of doing that other than keeping a duplicate question open (e.g. put a bounty on the old question). I know you didn't post it as a duplicate intentionally, but the policies and procedure are fairly clear for what to do with a duplicate question. It also doesn't feel like this issue has a level of urgency which would justify deviating from normal procedure.

Comment: Yes, you're correct that the issue is that [the logo](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/askubuntu/img/logo.png) was designed to be placed over a red background (i.e. the background portion of the logo is transparent). Given that the background in that location of the SEDE site is white, it result in not being able to differentiate the the white "ubuntu" letters from the background.

Comment: as with any other bug of this nature - browser/version?

Comment: This question __might__ be helpful: https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19642